# Why irreducibility is an important concept in Flow Graphs?

Tags: graphs, compilers, software-engineering

[Here](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/dragon/w06/lectures/dfa3.pdf) is a definition of reducible flow graphs :

> A flow graph is reducible if every retreating edge in any DFST for
>   that flow graph is a back edge.

And the reasons why we care about `retreating/back edges`:

> 1. Proper ordering of nodes during iterative algorithm assures number of passes limited by the number of “nested” back edges.
> 2. Depth of nested loops upper-bounds the number of nested back edges.

With this explanation, I have more questions: why number of passes is important? why we want to know upper-bounds?

However, I still do not understand the **impact** of `irreducibility` . 
Why should we care about it? Will it make it harder to do loop flatten? What if we have irreducible flow graphs for program analysis?